# Wordpress get_posts not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using get_posts on a custom page template in order to list posts of a certain type (`business` in this case) that the user is the author of.
Here is the code I am trying:

```
$args = array(
    'author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => array(
      'publish',
      'pending',
    )
);
$listings = get_posts( $args );
```

However, this returns all the posts by the user, regardless of type. If I remove the `author` parameter, I get all the posts of the type I want, without taking the author into account. `get_current_user_id()` does indeed return the correct user ID, but I tried adding the ID in the code as well and I get the same results.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I am using WP 4.6.1

**UPDATE:** SQL logging reveals the following

If I use the `author` parameter:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_author IN (1)
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'project', 'profile', 'campaign')
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'))
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

If I leave the `author` parameter out:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'business'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'))
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Also, here is the custom post type declaration:

```
register_post_type('business',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'          => __( 'Businesses' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Business' ),
        'add_new'       =>  __( 'Add New Business' ),
        'add_new_item'  =>  __( 'Add New Business' ),
        'edit_item'     => __( 'Edit Business' )
      ),
      'public'      => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-store',
      'supports'    =>  array( 'thumbnail', 'title', 'editor', 'author' )
    )
  );
```

I am at a loss here...

Comment: Your arguments look correct. Can you show the `register_post_type` code, so we can see what you used to register the post type?

Comment: Also, it might be useful to [look at the SQL statement](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110266/how-to-print-the-excuted-sql-right-after-its-execution) that was run when you execute this `get_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
global $current_user;


$args = array(
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$listings = get_posts( $args );
?>
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers and provide explanations with the code.